# mov to mp4 with expo react native

Tags: reactjs, react-native, npm, mp4

I am using the expo camera ,if i am using the expo camera get i get the mov file in IOS but we want the mp4 file and i try to install the package of react-native-mov-to-mp4
https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-mov-to-mp4 its install in android but if I install in ios it's not reflected the library in pods and this library show me this error i shared in below:

> Could not find a declaration file for module 'react-native-mov-to-mp4'. '/Users/admiin/groupmembers/SmartEyeMobileApp/node_modules/react-native-mov-to-mp4/movToMp4.ios.js' implicitly has an 'any' type.
> Try `npm i --save-dev @types/react-native-mov-to-mp4` if it exists or add a new declaration (.d.ts) file containing `declare module 'react-native-mov-to-mp4';

And if I install the `npm i --save-dev @types/react-native-mov-to-mp4` that package it shows it's not in registry

> '@types/react-native-mov-to-mp4@*' is not in this registry.

Answer (score 1):

I can't comment so I'm writing this as an answer, I recently also came into this situation what worked for me basically

[React Native FFMPEg Package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ffmpeg-kit-react-native)

With the help of this library I was able to convert, reduce and take thumbnail of video please do check.

Comment: Now you can comment...

Answer (score 1):

This `@types/react-native-mov-to-mp4` library does not exist, so you can try option 2: `add a new declaration (.d.ts) file containing declare module 'react-native-mov-to-mp4';`:

1. Create a declaration file (like `typing.d.ts`) in root project folder
2. Add below code to that file:

```
declare module 'react-native-mov-to-mp4';
```